# Python code to read a csv file and create a master csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder let's say as 'input_Folder' which has a list of CSV files with data. I'm trying to write a Python code which reads this list of CSV files from the input_folder and creates a master CSV file with two columns.

The columns in the master CSV files are 'Scenario' and 'Status'.

Column Name requirement are as follows,
Scenario =  Name of the file from the directory and
Status = if the file has a value in the second row of second column then populate as 'Pass' else 'Fail'

Below is my code. After executing the code I'm able to see Master CSV created but with empty lines. I'm quite new to python so could somebody help me out here please

```py
import os
import csv

path = (Input file path)

with open("SUMMARY.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['SCENARIO', 'STATUS'])
    for files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
    with open("input_file.csv") as csv_file: #checking if the code is working for
        # one sample file
        all_rows = list(csv_file)
        line_count = 0
        for row in all_rows[1:2]:
            if line_count == 1:
                if row[1].value == None:
                    writer.writerow([os.path.basename(filename).split(".")[0], 'PASS'])
                else:
                    writer.writerow([os.path.basename(filename).split(".")[0], 'FAIL'])
            line_count += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt has three problems; it uses `os.walk` which traverses subdirectories (perhaps this is not a problem because your folder does not have subdirectories, but you should use the correct function for your use case regardless), and you are opening a file in the current directory instead of the one actually returned by `os.walk`. Finally, the input from `csv.reader` cannot be `None`; either the line contains fewer fields (in which case you cannot access the second field at all, and trying will get you an `IndexError`), or it contains an empty string. (More fundamentally, your indentation seems to be broken, but since you are not asking about a syntax error, I'm guessing your actual code doesn't have this problem.)

Here's a quick refactoring to use `glob.glob` instead of `os.walk`, assuming that the input CSV files have an empty field where you were looking for `None`. (It would obviously not be hard to change it to `if len(line) < 2:` if you wanted to, or cover both conditions.)

```
import csv
import os
from glob import glob

with open("SUMMARY.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    writer.writerow(['SCENARIO', 'STATUS'])
    for filename in glob(f"{path}/*.csv"):
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input_file:
            value = "FAIL"
            reader = csv.reader(input_file)
            for lineno, line in enumerate(reader, 1):
                if lineno != 2:
                    continue
                if line[1] != "":
                    value = "PASS"
                break
        writer.writerow([os.path.basename(filename).split(".")[0], value])
```

Tangentially perhaps notice also how I avoid having two variables with almost the same names `csvfile` and `csv_file`.

The logic writes `"FAIL"` if there is only one input line, too. (Refactored in response to a comment.)

Comment: Thanks a ton. I tried the same code above where I just replaced f"{path}/*.csv" to r"{path}/*.csv" since it was throwing unicode error and when I run it the summary report was created only for the files which had values in the second line. The files which only had header was not captured at all. I was expecting the file only header to be captured  in the Summary sheet as 'PASS' which is not happening. could you please help me

Comment: Changing from an f-string to an r-string makes no sense here. The `f` is what causes `{path}` to be replaced with its value; without it, Python will look for a file with literally that name. The `r` prefix only affects how backslashes are interpreted in strings, but there are no backslashes in this string,.

Comment: Updated to write "FAIL" if there is only a single line of input. You really should spell out your requirements in the question, though (or ask a new question if you need to change things more fundamentally).

Comment: Sorry if my question was vague, Code works as expected but the only problem is there are empty rows in between the lines and there is also one more row for the summary file itself :( should i add a piece of code to remove the empty lines and summary file row. I am sorry if my question is senseless since I am very new to coding

Comment: I can't repro that, but I also don't think you have used my code verbatim because I just fixed a silly typo. See if you can make sense of this demo and perhaps use that to produce a [mre]: https://ideone.com/hOtl72

Comment: the last line had an issue so I fixed and executed it while i copy pasted your code. Thanks a lot for your guidance. I will have a look at the demo and try to repro accordingly :)

Answer (score -1):

Please review my code below. Create a folder where you'd like all your CSV files to live and run the code below to join all CSV files into a df. For this example, I named my folder,  "Folder"

The "*.csv" finds all csv files in "Folder"

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import glob

# Create a folder where you want to dump files
all_files = glob.glob("Folder/*.csv")

print(all_files)
li = []

# join csv files
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

# df = combined csv files
df = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Requiring the OP to install Pandas just to read CSV files is severe overkill. Python itself can read CSV files without the need to install a humongous third-party library.

Comment: Also, the OP asks to extract a field from each input file, not just concatenate them in their entirety.